# Why JS.ERB is so bad?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I would like to have more information and concrete cases how bad is JS.ERB in a Rails application.

I have something in mind:

1. Lack of flexibility
2. Complexity
3. Mix Javascript + Ruby ( possible + HTML) code

Comment: I think it is great, particularly for building apps that work with or without js, and with a minimum of duplication. Having access to all of your objects and partials and whatnot make life much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The worst thing about this is that javascript is supposed to be client side language and building it server side seems at least awkward.

Apart from that, you will get a major performance hit if you are not able to precompile your assets - every request for javascript file in production server has to get through your rails application to render erb correctly. (If your .js.erb files depends on variable, request related values). If you avoid js.erb files and have .js files only, those files are completely static and can be served directly by the server without touching your application at all.

There are naturally couple of exceptions - I personally allow myself to use erbized javascript files to avoid hardcoding urls or other application constants. For me, the rule of thumb is - if erbization doesn't stop you from precompiling and will make your code cleaner and more resilient, just go for it.

Naturally there are some reasons not to do the above as well - in the ideal world I would love my server side application to be pure API consumed by another, pure static js application. Using erbized javascript is an extra obstacle from splitting your app in half when it grow too much.

Comment: Not just awkward. Dynamic JavaScript is known to be a source of security weakness.

Answer (score 2):

js.erb is generation of javascript with ruby, right? To me this has an obvious "code smell", of code generation.  Whenever someone resorts to using one (more familiar) language to generate another (less familiar) language, I would question the quality of the generated code. In this case a javascript guru would probably look a the generated code and be thinking "WTF?, why would someone do __ this way?". There are probably going to be a lot of things that work, but are not how an experienced javascript developer would do it. This can lead to performance issues, maintainability issues, and just plain bad code.

Just my opinion.

Comment: linuxdan - no that's not what happens, the overall code file is javascript but it has mixed in small bits of ruby that control the generation of the javascript.  For example you might have a ruby loop that iterates through items in the db, generating some inline json constants.

Comment: That's what I call code generation.

Comment: "Whenever someone resorts to using one (more familiar) language to generate another (less familiar) language, I would question the quality of the generated code." You mean like using an ORM to write SQL? Or say a C++ compiler to write assembler? Or maybe CoffeeScript/TypeScript to write JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

*Warning - Highly Opinionated answer to follow.  Moderators will probably delete!*

I can't agree more, in fact I am a bit of a nut about this, and have been using [react.rb](http://reactrb.org) to get all of our views into straight ruby, no JS, ERB, at all.

My specific reason beyond what you mention is this:  The mental power it takes to constantly shift between different languages is huge, and largely taken for granted by developers.  We just don't notice how much energy its taking.  In otherwords we have become like frogs in the pot of water, and we keep making our programming lives more complex with all these languages and sublanguages (we were programming in 5 different languages in one site) and while you get used to it, once you stop, and stick to one language (ruby in our case) you just say whew!

While I have no specific study to prove this, I think its just a form of multitasking which is a known evil. i.e. https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/brain-wise/201209/the-true-cost-multi-tasking

Comment: I have to say I agree with the exception BroiSatse mentions in his answer.  We do use erb for that limited case, but really we are just extending ruby with the addition of the <% ... %> syntax.